# Setting podManagementPolicy for a StatefulSet

Tags: kubernetes, linode, kubernetes-statefulset

I am using a StatefulSet to deploy my application and I have 10 replicas. Because each pod waits for the previous pod to be ready, it takes a long time to spin up my cluster. I found the [podManagementPolicy option](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#pod-management-policies) on the Kubernetes documentation. I want to set `podManagementPolicy` to `Parallel` so my pods don't wait for each other (which I don't need) and my build time is shorter.

However, I am getting the following error when I try to set `podManagementPolicy` to `Parallel`:

> The StatefulSet "xxx" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', 'updateStrategy', 'persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy' and 'minReadySeconds' are forbidden

Here is the yaml file for my StatefulSet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: xxx
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: xxx
  serviceName: "xxx"
  replicas: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xxx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: xxx
          image: xxx.com/xxx:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerregistrykey
```

I am using an [Linode LKE](https://www.linode.com/products/kubernetes/) cluster and the Kubernetes version is 1.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are on K8s version **1.24** or above as mentioned in error you can only update a few fields in **statefulset** unlike **Deployment** or **POD**.

So you have to **delete** and **re-apply** the new changes is the only solution.

You can also create the **new** **stateful** set with a different name and keep the **label** same as the existing running one.

Once one stateful set is up & running you can remove the **older** one and **service** will forward the traffic to new running replicas, guessing there won't be any issues with data as you mentioned about it being fine to run **parallel**.

In case you have a requirement to use existing **PVC** to store the **data**, deleting the **statefulset** is only solution i am seeing.